# Поиск дружественных чисел

Tags: python, оптимизация

Задача: найти все пары дружественных чисел, меньших 10000. Дружественными называются два числа, если каждое из них равно сумме делителей другого. Равные числа дружественными не считаются.

У меня самого есть 2 кода:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(1, 10001):
    k = 0
    n = 0
    for x in range(1, i):
        if i % x == 0:
            k += x
    for j in range(1, k):
        if k % j == 0:
            n += j
    if i == n and i < k:
        print(i, k)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - a)
```

Этот выполняется за 14 с мелочью секунд, но по мне это как-то слишком долго.

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(1, 10001):
    k = sum(filter(lambda x: i % x == 0, range(1, i)))
    n = sum(filter(lambda x: k % x == 0, range(1, k)))
    if i == n and i < k:
        print(i, k)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - a)
```

Попробовал упростить задачу с помощью анонимных функций и итераторов - на 1 секунду программа выполняется быстрее (что интересно, профайлер Pycharm для первого решения выдает такой же результат (14 сек), но если для второго решения запустить профайлер, то он покажет 27 секунд, а не 13, с чем это связано я не понимаю)

Скорее всего есть решения быстрее, поэтому спрашиваю совета.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если убрать лишние вычисления и не считать дважды для одного числа, то на моей машине в 3.5 раза быстрее будет:

```
divsum = [0]*10001

for i in range(1, 10001):
    k = 0
    for x in range(1, 1 + i // 2):
        if i % x == 0:
            k += x
    if k <= 10000:
        divsum[i] = k
        if divsum[k] == i:
            print(i, k)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - a)
```

А если оптимизировать, считая делители только до корня из числа (парный делитель получить нетрудно), то быстрее в 70 раз:

```
divsum = [0]*10001

for i in range(1, 10001):
    k = 1
    x = 2
    while  x*x < i:
        if i % x == 0:
            k += x
            k += i//x
        x += 1
    if x*x==i:
        k += x

    if k <= 10000:
        divsum[i] = k
        if k < i and divsum[k] == i:
            print(i, k)
```

Comment: Невероятно! 
Один лишь вопрос: зачем делать k += i // x, я не совсем вникаю в это

Comment: Это же просто второй делитель) Который больше корня от i =)

Comment: Если мы нашли, что 28 делится на 2, то можем добавить сразу и 2, и 14=28/2