# Помощь в улучшении эффективности алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм, kotlin

Практикуюсь в решении задачек в Codewars.
Застопорился на следующей:
Есть число, например, `42`. Его делителями являются числа `1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42`. Сумма квадратов всех делителей равна `2500`. А `2500`, в свою очередь, является квадратом целого числа `50`.

Так вот, на вход функции мы подаем промежуток чисел от `m` до `n`. Необходимо написать алгоритм, который в промежутке от `m` до `n` найдет все такие целые числа, которые бы соответствовали указанным выше условиям - сумма квадратов их делителей должна сама быть квадратом целого числа.

Функция возвращает массив массивов - например, в промежутке от 1 до 250 три числа соответствуют условиям, а выходе получим массив `[[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]]`, где первое число - само удовлетворяющее условиям число, а второе - сумма квадратов его делителей.

Если что, сама задачка: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55aa075506463dac6600010d

Я написал вполне работающий алгоритм. Однако Codewars иногда отклоняет решения, если считает алгоритм неэффективным. Для повышения эффективности алгоритма я сделал две его модификации:

1. У числа не бывает целочисленного делителя больше, чем половина этого числа, поэтому выходим из цикла `for`, когда проходим половину числа
2. Если число нечетное, то все его делители тоже нечетные, поэтому при проверке нечетного числа в цикле for движемся с шагом 2: `1,3,5` и т.д.

Несмотря на это, мой алгоритм Codewars отклоняет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как возможно ещё улучшить скорость этого алгоритма? Возможно я выбрал неправильный подход к решению?
И второй вопрос, вытекающий из моих оптимизаций. Я напихал много различных проверок на чётность, на то, больше число половины проверяемого числа или нет. Насколько оно стоит того, может, эти проверки только замедляют код, а не избавляют программу от лишних вычислений?

Код:

```
fun listSquared(m: Long, n: Long): String {
    var finalArray = mutableListOf<List<Long>>()
    var sum: Long
            for (i in m..n){
        sum = 0
            
        if (i % 2 == 0L){
            for (j in 1..i){
                if (i % j == 0L){
                    sum += j.toDouble().pow(2).toLong()
                    if (i/j < 2) break // у числа не бывает делителя больше, чем половина этого числа
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (j in 1..i step 2){ // если число нечетное, то все его делители тоже нечетные
                if (i % j == 0L){
                    sum += j.toDouble().pow(2).toLong()
                    if (i/j < 2) break
                }
            }
        }

        if ((sqrt(sum.toDouble()) % 1.0) == 0.0){
            finalArray.add(listOf(i, sum))
        }
    }
    return finalArray.toString()
}
```

Comment: на английском оверфлоу есть решения на пайтоне, там используется корень числа. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53826181/16266470

Comment: [На Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208256/1208281#1208281)  (после "А если оптимизировать...")

Comment: И вот такого `j.toDouble().pow(2).toLong()`, пожалуйста, не делайте. `j*j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, действительно. Они только замедляют. Ведь проверяемых чисел будет меньше всего в 4 раза, что сожрется обработкой ифоф.

Есть два варианта не требующих сложной математики: первый -- воспользоваться тем, что каждому делителю числа есть парный и перебирать в O(sqrt(n)) меньше. Второй -- грязный предподсчет :)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Алгоритм прошёл.